# Ionic4: Email Passwordless Auth - user is not registered

Tags: firebase-authentication, ionic4

I want users to login passwordless through an email link in my webapp. In the future, I also want to make this work on android/ios, but for now I am happy to make this work on web. 
I am able to send the email, but the click on the link does not result in that the user is being created in Firebase.

I tried many tutorials, now I am using those two great tutorials for my work: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAG7Oig34RY&t=43s
https://medium.com/@vivek040997/how-to-implement-firebase-email-link-passwordless-login-in-ionic-4-for-android-4c61f331c4a0

Home HTML:

```
    <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="email"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
<ion-button
    expand="block"
    [disabled]="emailSent"
    (click)="sendEmailLink(email)"
    >Login</ion-button
  >
```

Home.page.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Platform, AlertController, NavController } from "@ionic/angular";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  hasVerifiedEmail = true;
  sentTimestamp;
  email;
  emailSent = false;
  errorMessage;
  user;

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,private alertController: AlertController,
    private navCtrl: NavController) {

    }


  async sendEmailLink() {
    var actionCodeSettings = {
      // URL you want to redirect back to. Enter the Firebase hosting url here.
      url: "http://localhost:8101/home",
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      iOS: {
        bundleId: "com.firebaseemail.linkauth"
      },
      android: {
        packageName: "com.firebaseemail.linkauth"
      }
    };
try {
      await this.afAuth.auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
        this.email,
        actionCodeSettings
      );
      this.presentAlert("Mail Sent", "Check your email for login link");
      this.emailSent = true;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      this.presentAlert("Error", "There was an error in sending mail");
      this.errorMessage = err.message;
    }
  }

  async presentAlert(title, message) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: title,
      message: message,
      buttons: ["OK"]
    });
await alert.present();
  }

}
```

I manage to get the email being sent to the email. I also have the localhost url whitelisted in my firebase configuration. 
But I guess I miss the function to actually register the user? I just don't understand how to add this part.

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have followed the tutorial too literally.

Please review the steps that you have taken and make sure you have picked proper names in each instance.

### Bundle Name

I can see in the snippet you have posted that you have copied the package name `com.firebaseemail.linkauth` which was only an example.

Each app in the world has to have a unique package/bundle id. The common format is to reverse your apps website domain. So if you owned the domain www.microsoft.com and you wanted to release awesome app you would probably pick something like `com.microsoft.awesomeapp` for your bundle name.

It doesn't have to be this - it can be any text you want, but this is what people use because nobody else is likely to have used your own website address. It's an easy way for everyone in the world to generate their own unique package names without clashing.

Following on from this there are several other spots in the tutorial where you may have  made similar mistakes, so review all the example placeholders and check you have used your own unique values.

### Return Url

In step 6 it explains how you can set up hosting and why you need it.

Re-read that section, follow its set up instructions.

You will need that url for later on.

See in the tutorial In step 8, section 2, where it says this:

```
  // URL you want to redirect back to. Enter the Firebase hosting url here.
  url: "https://yourprojectname.firebaseapp.com/",
```

It says enter your Firebase hosting url, but you have put the wrong thing - a localhost url:

```
  // URL you want to redirect back to. Enter the Firebase hosting url here.
  url: "http://localhost:8101/home",
```

You just need to follow the tutorial and make sure you read every instruction and do the correct thing. It all seems to be there for a full solution.

Comment: Thanks rtpHarry for going through the details of the tutorial! 

The URL which differed was ok, since I have my project still on localhost. However, I made it work (at least for testing on web, mobile is not included yet) by adding several lines to the constructor, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth